# Append Annotation within a ArcGIS geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, annotation

I have a large data set of sanitary sewer pipes. I am making a map book with data driven pages and need to move the labels around so that they are not overlapping the edges of the page and the manhole and catch basin labels are legible as well. I have converted the labels to annotation in the database and can easily edit the labels, moving them. I noticed that not all the features were labeled, so I check the unplaced annotations. Everything is supposedly placed. I realized that I had the connect features option check in Placement Properties > Label Density prior to converting to annotation. I believe this is why many of the labels are not showing up. Is there a way to update or fix this? I have about half the labels moved already and don't want to start over.